# Handle image before adding file in filepond

Tags: javascript, filepond

I am using [filepond library](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) for uploading images to my server.

You can handle image after image adding action like this:

```
pond.on('addfile', (file) => {
    // Do something with file...
});
```

But i want to play with image before adding this. Because, if filepond has preview feature, it is showing original image when you droped an image. But if i want to add watermark to image, and want to display edited image on the preview area, i don't know how to do this. I want something like this:

```
pond.on('beforeadd', (file) => {
    const newFile = addWatermark(file);
    return newFile;
});
```

So i can show edited image in the preview area.

I know i can do this with transform plugin but it is firing only while image is processing. I want to add edited file directly preview.

Comment: Use the FilePond file poster plugin and update the `poster` metadata to render a new image poster. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-poster/

Comment: @Rik thanks but, Fileposter is plugin, creating preview for non image files. Right? I don't understand how to use images.